# viewing complex numbers as a linear transformation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am studying an intro to complex analysis and geometry book in order to become more adept with complex numbers and hopefully eventually the basics of complex analysis.

I love the explanations but I am having a lot of trouble with the exercises.
The following question is one of them.

Suppose one has, $L$ , the $ 2 \times 2$ matrix

\begin{array}{cc}
a  & -b \\
b  &  a  
\end{array}

A) suppose that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. What is the geometric meaning of multiplication by $L$.

B) suppose that $b = 0$. What is the geometric meaning of multiplication by 
$L$.

This is the part of the book where he talks about viewing complex numbers as a general linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$, namely $(x,y)  \longrightarrow (ax - by, bx + ay)$.
Thank you for any help or relevant references.

Comment: Related: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886872/history-of-the-matrix-representation-of-complex-numbers
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845907/usefulness-of-alternative-constructions-of-the-complex-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** A) $1 = a^2 + b^2 $ so there is a $\theta$ with $a = \cos\theta$ and 
$b=-\sin\theta$, then this is a rotation of an angle $\theta$ around the origin.

B) the transformation is an enlargement of $x,y$ with the same ratio.

Comment: thanks. do you know of a book or notes that talk about geometric meanings of matrix transformations.

Comment: I have no idea. Almost every course covering the subject should contain such content.

Comment: [This one](http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/lineartransformations/) looks nice.

Comment: thank you. I am going to check the question as closed because between your answer and the link, I should be able to understand. thanks again.

Comment: @mark leeds: thanks.