# Usefulness of alternative constructions of the complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, visualization

Complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are usually constructed as $\mathbb{R}^2$ together with a suitable multiplication.
But this is not the only possible way, one can get to the complex numbers. One alternative would be via $\mathbb{R}[x]/{\left< x^2+1\right>}$, but I have never seen this one be used in practice.

When visualizing complex number one usually uses the fact tha
  and then visualizes what happens in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
,

My  question is: 1) Are there any instances of theorems or definitions involving complex numbers, were one is better off* using a *different* construction than $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? (You may also answer with the contrapositive and describe a situation were using $\mathbb{R}^2$ makes everything worse.)

2) A special case of 1): Are there known constructions of complex numbers other than $\mathbb{R}^2$  that can also be given a geometric/visual interpretation ?
One reason the construction via $\mathbb{R}^2$ is more popular than $\mathbb{R}[x]/{\left< x^2+1\right>}$ is surely due to the fact that by this interpretation the complex numbers (an also their arithmetic operations) have a geometric meaning - whereas visualizing equivalence classes of polynomials is not so easy.

*this could mean anything that helps our understanding: For example it could mean that the proof becomes conceptually easier, the situation is easier to visualize etc.

Comment: The first two constructions of $\,\Bbb C\,$ are essentially the same, i.e. the first arises from choosing the normal forms $\,a + bx\,$ for elements of $\,R[x]/(x^2+1)\,$ and then transporting the ring structure to these normal forms, see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/628232/242) for further details.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, and there are also other constructions, that are in a sense isomorphic. But are they somewhere useful ?

Answer (score 1):

Original poster misunderstands relationship between $⟨1,i⟩$ with $i^2=-1$ (said $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $\mathbb{R}[i]/{⟨i^2+1⟩}$. These definitions of a ring extension are not fundamentally different, but the latter starts from a property that the extension must acquire (namely, a new $\sqrt{-1}$ element), whereas the former shows its vector space structure over the ground field ℝ explicitly, in the form of standard basis. Original poster “never saw this $\mathbb{R}[i]/{⟨i^2+1⟩}$ be used in practice” only because degree-2 polynomials on $i$ are immediately reduced to lesser-degree polynomials, yielding aforementioned 2-dimensional vector space.

Yes, there exists another broadly known representation of complex numbers, namely by two numerical parameters: non-negative **modulus** (absolute value), and angular **argument**. It is related to “$\mathbb{R}^2$” is the same way as polar coordinates are related to Cartesian ones. Where and why is it convenient? Complex numbers are a handy metaphor for linear transformations of Euclidean 2-vectors that preserve (signed) angles. Such transformations include [rotations as complex numbers of the modulus 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group), dilations (homotheties) as real numbers, and all their compositions as products. Saying our transformation is $r\exp(iθ), r≥0$ answers two questions:

- What happens to vector lengths? (are multiplied by *r*)
- By which angle are all vectors rotated? (*θ*)

Using “$a + bi$” parametrization indeed gives Cartesian coordinates of the image of one of standard basis vectors, some expressions of orthogonal projections for a general Euclidean vector and its image, but is far less sensible geometrically.