# Two different matrix representations of complex numbers

Tags: matrices, soft-question, complex-numbers, field-theory

There are two different ways to represent a complex number with $2 \times 2$ real matrices:
$$
\rho: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R}) \qquad 
\rho(z)=\rho(a+ib)= 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
a&b  \\
 -b &a
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and
$$
\bar\rho: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R}) \qquad 
\bar\rho(z)=\bar\rho(a+ib)= 
\left[ 
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
a&-b  \\
 b &a
\end{array}
\right]
$$
We can find one or the other in many sources, and somewhere both, as in 
[History of the matrix representation of complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886872/history-of-the-matrix-representation-of-complex-numbers)

Clearly this two representations generate the same subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ but ve have: $\bar \rho(z)=\rho(\bar z)$.

The existence of this double representation  has some (hidden for me) significance or is purely fortuitous ?

Comment: There are actually lots of ways: for any matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2 = -I$, the subring generated by $I$ and $A$ is isomorphic to the complex numbers. Although, I think the one you list is the only one where complex conjugation is given by the transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s an arbitrariness in putting $i$ above the real axis instead of below. This is the same.

The complex numbers have a fundamental analytical and algebraic symmetry given by the complex conjugation. Algebraically, this just reflects the arbitrary choice of one of the roots of $X^2 + 1$ and expressing the other one in terms of the chosen one.