# Could anyone help me. How can I proof a field in matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

(Matrix)

$$I_2\text{ and } J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 &0
\end{pmatrix} ∈ M_2(\mathbb{R})$$

Show that $C = [aI_2 + bJ | a,b ∈\mathbb{R}]$ is a ﬁeld.

I can't solve this problem, could anyone help me?
Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Are you defining the matrices as $diag(a_1,...a_n)$?

Comment: No but I couldn't find the right format for the matrices.

Comment: 2 x 2 matrices.

Comment: I edited it. It is simply the field of complex numbers in disguise. I think this question gives you all the resources: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886872/history-of-the-matrix-representation-of-complex-numbers

Comment: @Bcpicao: Not necessarily "in disguise". E T Copson, in his Introduction to the Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable, defines this set to *be* the complex numbers. He does this to avoid "the undefined symbol" $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Indeed, although I maintain my formulation for two reasons: firstly, historically, that representation came afterwards. Secondly, the OP is clearly more familiar with the ad hoc representation of the complex numbers. I admit who's in disguise depends on your reference frame.

Comment: Why can’t you solve it? What exactly are you getting stuck on? Do you know the properties that a field must have? Are there any particular properties that you’re having trouble demonstrating?

Answer (score 1):

It is $\mathbb{C}$, the field of complex numbers. In fact, you can see the matrix $I$ as $1$, and $J$ as $i$, since it has the same properties (show it in the proof). Then you need to verify that the product is commutative and every matrix (i.e. every complex number) has a multiplicative inverse. The calculations are simple, since you have $2\times 2$ matrices.